# Collision of two waves with phase difference

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, nonlinear, fourier-analysis, wave-propagation

I am trying to produce collisional figures from this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.07165.pdf.
But failed to see the phase effect. In my case it just passes through one another. It basically solve a nonlinear Schrödinger in fast-Fourier transform method following eq. (39).[image]

Here is my code

````
 ```m = \[HBar] = g = 1;
nmax = 4000;
a = 100;
\[CapitalDelta] = a/(nmax + 1);
xgrid = Range[nmax]*\[CapitalDelta];
W[x_] := 0;
Wgrid = W /@ xgrid;

x0 = 30; 
\[Mu] = 0.08318075081482376;
vv = Normalize[
    N[0.615911009631103`/(
      1 + 0.27592297032567903` Cosh[0.6407865009143596` (xgrid - x0)])
       E^(1*I*xgrid + 180 \[Degree])]] + 
   Normalize[
    N[0.615911009631103`/(
      1 + 0.27592297032567903` Cosh[0.6407865009143596` (xgrid - 80)])
       E^-(1*I*xgrid)]];
ListLinePlot[
 Join[{{0, 0}}, {xgrid, vv/Sqrt[\[CapitalDelta]]}\[Transpose], {{a, 0}}], 
 PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"x", "\[Psi](x)"}]

propApprox[Wt_, \[Kappa]_?NumericQ, \[CapitalDelta]t_?NumericQ, 
   M_Integer /; M >= 1, v0_ /; VectorQ[v0, NumericQ]] := 
  Module[{\[Lambda], Ke, propKin, propPot2, prop},
   \[Lambda] = -I*N[\[CapitalDelta]t/(M*\[HBar])];
   Ke = Exp[\[Lambda]*Range[nmax]^2*(\[Pi]^2 \[HBar]^2)/(2 m a^2)*0.5];
   propKin[v_] := FourierDST[Ke*FourierDST[v, 1], 1];
   propPot2[t_, v_] := 
    Exp[\[Lambda]/
       2*((Wt[#, t] & /@ xgrid) + \[Kappa]*Abs[v]^2/\[CapitalDelta] - 
         Abs[v]/\[CapitalDelta]^((1/2)))]*v;
   prop[v_, t_] := 
    propPot2[t + (3 \[CapitalDelta]t)/(4 M), 
     propKin[propPot2[t + \[CapitalDelta]t/(4 M), v]]];
   {Range[0, M]/M \[CapitalDelta]t, 
     FoldList[prop, v0, Range[0, M - 1]/M \[CapitalDelta]t]}\[Transpose]];
With[{\[Kappa] = 1, \[CapitalDelta]t = 100, M = 4000},
 \[Rho] = ArrayPad[
   Abs[propApprox[W[#1] &, \[Kappa], \[CapitalDelta]t, M, vv][[All, 
      2]]]^2/\[CapitalDelta], {{0, 0}, {1, 1}}];
 Pq = ArrayPlot[Reverse[Transpose[\[Rho]]], 
   DataRange -> {{0, \[CapitalDelta]t}, {0, a}}, 
   ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", MaxPlotPoints -> 200];
 Show[Pq, AspectRatio -> 1/2, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> Automatic, 
  ImageSize -> 1000, LabelStyle -> {24, Bold, Large, Black}, 
  FrameLabel -> {{Style["x", FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 
      FontSlant -> "Italic", FontWeight -> Bold, FontSize -> 30], 
     None}, {Style["t", FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 
      FontSlant -> "Italic", FontWeight -> Bold, FontSize -> 30], 
     Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(V\), \(0\)]\)= 0, \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(N\), \
\(1\)]\)= 20, k= 2, K= 0", FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 
      FontSlant -> "Italic", FontWeight -> Bold, FontSize -> 30]}}]]```
````

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All examples from the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.07165.pdf) can be solved with `NDSolve` while solution with fast-Fourier transform method diverges for all cases $N_1=N_2=20, k=0.1, phase$. Code with `NDSolve` can be written as follows

```
pse[x_, t_, 
  mu_] := -3 mu Exp[-I mu t]/(1 + 
     Sqrt[1 + 9 mu/2] Cosh[Sqrt[-2 mu x^2]])

n[mu_] := 
 4/3 (Log[(Sqrt[-9 mu/2] + 1)/(Sqrt[9 mu/2 + 1])] - Sqrt[-9 mu/2])


N1=N2=20;
mu1 = mu /. 
  FindRoot[n[mu] == N1, {mu, -2/9 + 1/1000}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]

L = 100; k0 = .1; xm = 65; p = 0; eq = 
 I D[u[x, t], t] + 1/2 D[u[x, t], x, x] - Abs[u[x, t]]^2 u[x, t] + 
   Abs[u[x, t]] u[x, t] == 0;
ic = u[x, 0] == 
  Exp[I k0 x + I p] pse[x + xm, 0, mu1] + 
   Exp[-I k0 x] pse[x - xm, 0, mu1]; bc = {u[L, t] == 
    ic[[2]] /. {x -> L}, u[-L, t] == ic[[2]] /. {x -> -L}};
```

Visualization of initial state

```
Plot[Abs[ic[[2]]], {x, -L, L}, PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "\[Psi](x)"}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Visualization of numerical solution

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{eq, bc, ic}, u, {x, -L, L}, {t, 0, 1500}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
      "MinPoints" -> 1001, "MaxPoints" -> 4001, 
      "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}}, MaxSteps -> 10^6];

DensityPlot[Abs[sol[x, t]], {t, 0, 1000}, {x, -L, L}, 
 ColorFunction -> "PlumColors", FrameLabel -> Automatic, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, AspectRatio -> 1/2, 
 PlotLabel -> 
  "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(N\), \(1\)]\) = \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(N\), \(2\
\)]\) = 20, k = 0.1, p = 0"]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Case `N1=N2=20; k0=0.1; p=Pi`

[image: Figure 3]

Case `N1=N2=20; k0=0.1; p=Pi/2`
[image: Figure 4]

Comment: Thanks again @AlexTrounev. I was looking forward to fixing my code. Actually, I solved mu1 separately and put it in the wave function for different particle numbers. I defined initial wavefunctions with speed and phase but it seems the phase part is not working in the FFT algorithm in my code so I was unable to see the reflection. Nevertheless, your code fixes my immediate problem.

Comment: I am writing a review paper on that topic where I intend to put these dynamics. I would like to acknowledge you in that review and my forthcoming works if you do not have any problems. If you give me your full name and affiliation it would be a great help. You can see my works here https://arxiv.org/search/?query=argha+debnath&searchtype=all&source=header    @AlexTrounev

Comment: @ArghaDebnath Thank you very much for your papers. Your solution is very interesting. We also have published several papers concerning nonlinear Schrödinger in 2D and 3D like this one   https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/adts.201900186

Answer (score 8):

I am sorry but with the shape of the code in the question and without knowing the underlying algorithm I did not really bother trying to figure out what exactly goes on with it. I wrote my own version based on the *Wikipedia* article [Split-step_method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-step_method) and loosely also on this *stackoverflow* question [Split step Fourier propagation - Beam propagation method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47539234).

For problems like this it is often useful to test/benchmark against reference solutions. For this purpose lets consider the time evolution of a Gaussian pulse with the free Schrödinger equation:

```
schroedingerEq=0==I D[psi[t,x],t]+1/2 D[psi[t,x],x,x]+(-Abs[psi[t,x]]^2psi[t,x]+Abs[psi[t,x]]psi[t,x]);
freeSchroedingerEq=schroedingerEq/.Abs[psi[t,x]]->0;

psiRef=DSolveValue[{freeSchroedingerEq,psi[0,x]==Exp[-I x]Exp[-x^2]},psi,{t,x}]
```

which gives for `psiRef` the simple analytical expression
$$
\psi(t,x)=\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\frac{t-2 \mathrm{i} x^2+2 x}{-4 t+2 \mathrm{i}}}}{\sqrt{1+2 \mathrm{i} t}}.
$$

Now lets implement some solution methods. We begin with a brute-force Mathematica implementation based on `NDSolves` PDE capabilities:

```
Clear[solveNDSolve]
solveNDSolve[tmax_,L_][psi0_,eq_:schroedingerEq]:=NDSolveValue[
    {eq,psi[t,-L/2]==psi[t,L/2],psi[0,x]==psi0[x]},
    psi,
    {t,0,tmax},{x,-L/2,L/2},
    Method->{"PDEDiscretization"->{
        "MethodOfLines",
        "DiscretizedMonitorVariables"->True,
        "TemporalVariable"->t, 
        "SpatialDiscretization"->{"TensorProductGrid","MinPoints"->400,"MaxPoints"->1000, "DifferenceOrder"->"Pseudospectral"}
    }},
    PrecisionGoal->6
]
```

The second solution method I implemented is a naive split-step (Fourier) method based on the references mentioned earlier:

```
ClearAll[solveSSFM]
solveSSFM[n_/;EvenQ[n],dt_,tmax_,L_][psi0_,Nop_]:=Module[{dx,xi,dk,ki,psi,tj,sol,j,},
    dx=L/n;
    xi=Table[-L/2+1/n+i*dx,{i,0,n-1}]; (* position grid (including the origin) *)
    dk=2Pi/(L); (* % wave vector increment *)
    ki=dk/Sqrt[2](Range[1,n/2]~Join~(-Reverse[Range[0,n/2-1]])); (* momentum grid *)

    psi=psi0[#]&/@xi; (* Inital waveform *)

    tj=Table[t,{t,0,tmax,dt}]; (* list of time steps *)
    sol=Table[{{t,x},0},{t,tj},{x,xi}]; (* preallocate solution matrix *)
    sol[[1,All,2]]=psi;  (* insert intial waveform *)

    For[j=2,j<=Length[tj],j++,
        psi=MapThread[Exp[+I dt Nop[#1,#2]]&,{psi,xi}]*psi; (* apply the interaction operator *)
        psi=InverseFourier[Exp[-I ki*ki*dt]*Fourier[psi,FourierParameters->{1,- 1}],FourierParameters->{1,- 1}]; (* perform the step *)
        sol[[j,All,2]]=psi; (* insert the current psi into the solution matrix*)
    ];
    Interpolation[Flatten[sol,1],InterpolationOrder->1]
]
```

with the number of Fourier modes `n`, the fixed time step `dt`, the integration time `tmax`, the interval size `L` ($x\in(L/2,L/2]$), the initial condition `psi0` and the interaction operator/term `Nop`, which can be a function of `psi` and `x`. Following the references the implementation of `solveSSFM` is almost straightforward with one exception: which flavor of fast Fourier transform (FFT) -- `Fourier` and `InverseFourier` -- to use and how to choose and order the corresponding wave numbers `ki`. I figured the current implementation out by consulting the documentation for `Fourier` and trial and error to match the reference solution `psiRef`. For some reason the factor `1/Sqrt[2]` seems necessary to ensure the right timescale.

Lets try to reproduce our reference solution using our two numerical methods:

```
L=100;tmax=5;
ics=Exp[-I #] Exp[-#^2]&;
solNDSolve=solveNDSolve[tmax,L][ics,freeSchroedingerEq];
solSSFM=Quiet@solveSSFM[1000,0.01,tmax,L][ics,0&];

Quiet@Grid[{DensityPlot[Abs[Symbol[#][t,x]],{t,0,tmax},{x,-L/2,+L/2},PlotPoints->100,PlotRange->All,FrameLabel->{"t","x"},PlotLegends->BarLegend[Automatic,LegendLabel->"Abs[psi[x]]"],PlotLabel->#,ImageSize->300]&/@{"psiRef","solSSFM","solNDSolve"}}]
With[{t=tmax},Plot[{Abs[psiRef[t,x]],Abs@solSSFM[t,x],Abs@solNDSolve[t,x]},{x,-L/2,L/2},PlotRange->All,PlotStyle->{Black,{Red,Dashed},{Blue,Dashed}},Frame->True,FrameLabel->{"x","psi[3,x]"},PlotLegends->Placed[{"reference","solSSFM","solNDSolve"},{Left,Top}]]]
```

which results in

> [image: psiRef density]

> [image: psiRef plot]

So for the free Schrödinger equation our methods seem to work well enough.

Now lets try a solution for the collision of two droplets. We begin by defining the droplet initial condition using Eqs. (9) and (10) of the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.07165.pdf):

```
psi0[mu_,x_]:=-((3mu)/(1+Sqrt[1+(9mu)/2]Cosh[Sqrt[-2mu x^2]]))
muofN[n_]/; NumericQ[n]:= Last@First@FindRoot[n==4/3 (Log[(Sqrt[-9/2 mu]+1)/Sqrt[9/2 mu+1]]-Sqrt[-9/2 mu]),{mu,-2/9+0.1,-2/9+$MachineEpsilon,\[Infinity]},MaxIterations->1000]
```

One explicit example studied in the paper is

```
L=100;tmax=80;
ics=Inactive[Function][x,Exp[I k x/2+vphi]psi0[muofN[N1],x+x0]+Exp[-I k x/2]psi0[muofN[N2],x-x0]]/.{x0->20,k->1,vphi->0,N1->0.1,N2->0.1}//Activate;
Plot[Abs@ics[x],{x,-L/2,L/2},Frame->True,FrameLabel->{"x","psi[0,x]"},PlotRange->All]
```

> [image: Droplet ICs]

for which free propagation

```
solNDSolve=solveNDSolve[tmax,L][ics,freeSchroedingerEq];
solSSFM=solveSSFM[100,0.1,tmax,L][ics,0&];

Quiet@Grid[{DensityPlot[Abs[Symbol[#][t,x]],{t,0,tmax},{x,-L/2,+L/2},PlotPoints->100,PlotRange->All,FrameLabel->{"t","x"},PlotLegends->BarLegend[Automatic,LegendLabel->"Abs[psi[x]]"],PlotLabel->#,ImageSize->300]&/@{"solSSFM","solNDSolve"}}]
```

leads to

> [image: Free droplets]

and using the nonlinear (interacting) Schrödinger equation

```
solNDSolve=solveNDSolve[tmax,L][ics,schroedingerEq];
solSSFM=solveSSFM[100,0.1,tmax,L][ics,-Abs[#]^2+Abs[#]&];

Quiet@Grid[{DensityPlot[Abs[Symbol[#][t,x]],{t,0,tmax},{x,-L/2,+L/2},PlotPoints->100,PlotRange->All,FrameLabel->{"t","x"},PlotLegends->BarLegend[Automatic,LegendLabel->"Abs[psi[x]]"],PlotLabel->#,ImageSize->300]&/@{"solSSFM","solNDSolve"}}]
```

results in

> [image: Interacting dropltes]

Compared to Fig. 5 (a) of the paper the time scale for the collision seems off: in the plots shown here the droplets meet/interact at $t\sim 40$ which happens at $t\sim 20$ in the paper. Maybe I screwed up a factor somewhere. Anyway I hope this answer is instructive enough to be helpful even without referencing the code in the original question explicitly.

Comment: Of course, it is helpful. Thanks for the help @N0va