# Solving logarithmic 2D Nonlinear GPE Equation

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, physics, nonlinear, difference-equations

I am trying to solve the logarithmic 2D Nonlinear GPE Equation from this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.10274.pdf. But failed to get the ground state solution and vortices. I tried to solve in cartesian coordinate. Here is a brief description of the problem and the results I am trying to get.[image]

Here is my code

```
boundary = 40;       xl = yl = -boundary;           xr = 
 yr = boundary;
 finalt = 2;
 seedwave[x_, y_] := Exp[-0.005 (x^2 + y^2) + I*svalue];
pnumber = 
 NIntegrate[
  Exp[-0.005 (x^2 + 
      y^2)], {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {y, -\[Infinity], \
\[Infinity]}];(*particle number check*)
svalue = 0; lvalue = 0;

sol = NDSolveValue[{D[\[Psi][x, y, t], 
      t] == -0.5 Laplacian[\[Psi][x, y, t], {x, y}] + 
      Abs[\[Psi][x, y, t]]^2 \[Psi][x, y, t] Log[
        Abs[\[Psi][x, y, t]]^2] - 
      I*0.25*value*Abs[\[Psi][x, y, t]]^4 \[Psi][x, y, t],
    \[Psi][xl, y, t] == \[Psi][xr, y, t] == 0,
    \[Psi][x, yl, t] == \[Psi][x, yr, t] == 0,
    \[Psi][x, y, 0] == seedwave[x, y]},
   \[Psi][x, y, t], {x, xl, xr}, {y, yl, yr}, {t, 0, finalt}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
       "MinPoints" -> 400, "MaxPoints" -> 800, 
       "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}}, MaxSteps -> 10^6];
Plot3D[Abs[sol[x, y, 1]], {x, xl, xr}, {y, yl, yr}]
Table[DensityPlot[Abs[sol], {x, xl, xr}, {y, yl, yr}, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 200, 
  ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", Frame -> True, 
  FrameTicks -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 200, ImageSize -> 350, 
  LabelStyle -> {24, Bold, Large, Black}, 
  FrameLabel -> {{Style["y", FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 
      FontSlant -> "Italic", FontWeight -> Bold, FontSize -> 30], 
     None}, {Style["x", FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 
      FontSlant -> "Italic", FontWeight -> Bold, FontSize -> 30], 
     Row[{Style["t=", FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 
        FontSlant -> "Italic", FontWeight -> Bold, FontSize -> 30], 
       t}]}}], {t, 0, finalt, 
  0.5*finalt}]

                                                    \
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not clear how in the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.10274.pdf) they normalize $\psi$ in Figure 1, may be as in equation (2). Without normalization we have

```
boundary = 40; xl = yl = -boundary; xr = yr = boundary;
finalt = 10;
seedwave[x_, y_] :=Exp[-0.005 (x^2 + y^2) + I*svalue ArcTan[x, y]] (x^2+y^2)^(svalue/2);
pnumber = 
 NIntegrate[
  Exp[-0.005 (x^2 + 
      y^2)], {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {y, -\[Infinity], \
\[Infinity]}](*particle number check*)
svalue = 0; lvalue = 0;


sol = NDSolveValue[{-D[\[Psi][x, y, t], 
      t] == -0.5 Laplacian[\[Psi][x, y, t], {x, y}] + 
     Abs[\[Psi][x, y, t]]^2 \[Psi][x, y, t] Log[
       Abs[\[Psi][x, y, t]]^2] - 
     I*0.25*lvalue*Abs[\[Psi][x, y, t]]^4 \[Psi][x, y, t], \[Psi][xl, 
     y, t] == seedwave[xl, y], \[Psi][xr, y, t] == 
    seedwave[xr, y], \[Psi][x, yl, t] == 
    seedwave[x, yl], \[Psi][x, yr, t] == 
    seedwave[x, yr], \[Psi][x, y, 0] == seedwave[x, y]}, \[Psi][x, y, 
   t], {x, xl, xr}, {y, yl, yr}, {t, 0, finalt}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
      "MinPoints" -> 400, "MaxPoints" -> 800, 
      "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}}, MaxSteps -> 10^6]
```

Note that we change sign at `D[\[Psi][x, y, t],t]` since we use imaginary time method. Visualization

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[ Abs[sol]^2 /. t -> finalt], {x, xl, xr}, {y, yl, yr},
  PlotRange -> All, MeshStyle -> White, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 PlotTheme -> "Marketing", PlotPoints -> 100] 
Plot[Evaluate[
  Table[Evaluate[Abs[sol]^2 /. {t -> t1, y -> 0}], {t1, 0, finalt, 
    1}]], {x, xl, xr}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Solutions with $L3\ne 0$ are unstable (central vortex decays into several vortexes), to simulate these solutions we use Pseudospectral option as follows (example with $S=L3=2$)

```
boundary = 40; xl = yl = -boundary; xr = yr = boundary;
finalt = 10; svalue = 2; lvalue = 2;
seedwave[x_, y_] := 
  Exp[-0.005 (x^2 + y^2) + 
     I*svalue ArcTan[x + I 10^-14, y]] (x^2 + y^2)^(svalue/2);
pnumber = 
 NIntegrate[
  Exp[-0.005 (x^2 + 
       y^2)]^2, {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {y, -\[Infinity], \
\[Infinity]}](*particle number check*)



sol = NDSolveValue[{-D[\[Psi][x, y, t], 
      t] == -0.5 Laplacian[\[Psi][x, y, t], {x, y}] + 
     Abs[\[Psi][x, y, t]]^2 \[Psi][x, y, t] Log[
       Abs[\[Psi][x, y, t]]^2] - 
     I*0.25*svalue*Abs[\[Psi][x, y, t]]^4 \[Psi][x, y, t], \[Psi][xl, 
     y, t] == seedwave[xl, y], \[Psi][xr, y, t] == 
    seedwave[xr, y], \[Psi][x, yl, t] == 
    seedwave[x, yl], \[Psi][x, yr, t] == 
    seedwave[x, yr], \[Psi][x, y, 0] == seedwave[x, y]}, \[Psi][x, y, 
   t], {x, xl, xr}, {y, yl, yr}, {t, 0, finalt}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
      "MinPoints" -> 100, "MaxPoints" -> 161, 
      "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}}, MaxSteps -> 10^6]
```

Visualization

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[ Abs[sol]^2 /. t -> finalt], {x, xl, xr}, {y, yl, yr},
  PlotRange -> All, MeshStyle -> White, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 PlotTheme -> "Marketing", PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Example with $S=1,L3=0$

```
boundary = 40; xl = yl = -boundary; xr = yr = boundary;
finalt = 10; svalue = 1; lvalue = 0;
seedwave[x_, y_] := 
  Exp[-0.005 (x^2 + y^2) + 
     I*svalue ArcTan[x + I 10^-14, y]] (x^2 + y^2)^(svalue/2);




sol = NDSolveValue[{-D[\[Psi][x, y, t], 
      t] == -0.5 Laplacian[\[Psi][x, y, t], {x, y}] + 
     Abs[\[Psi][x, y, t]]^2 \[Psi][x, y, t] Log[
       Abs[\[Psi][x, y, t]]^2] - 
     I*0.25*lvalue*Abs[\[Psi][x, y, t]]^4 \[Psi][x, y, t], \[Psi][xl, 
     y, t] == seedwave[xl, y], \[Psi][xr, y, t] == 
    seedwave[xr, y], \[Psi][x, yl, t] == 
    seedwave[x, yl], \[Psi][x, yr, t] == 
    seedwave[x, yr], \[Psi][x, y, 0] == seedwave[x, y]}, \[Psi][x, y, 
   t], {x, xl, xr}, {y, yl, yr}, {t, 0, finalt}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
      "MinPoints" -> 100, "MaxPoints" -> 161, 
      "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}}, MaxSteps -> 10^6]
```

Visualization
[image: Figure 3]

Comment: Thanks,  @AlexTrounev. Remember you helped me with this https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/266736/collision-of-two-waves-with-phase-difference. I used it in my recently published review https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fphy.2022.887338/full. I used your program in sec 3.3 fig.3. I acknowledged you in acknowledgment sec. In that review, I had to regenerate other people's results so we do not need to take permission and I was stuck with the said one until you helped.

Comment: I think I nearly solved this one @AlexTrounev. I submitted my thesis. So I am trying to regenerate other people's work to understand their topics at home so I will be bothering you with more nonlinear diff. equations from now on. I am trying for a postdoc. I do not want to go for teaching. Do you have any suggestions on what I can look forward to as I am getting only rejection emails. I know this station is not the right place to talk.

Comment: How can I density plot the phase of the sol?

Comment: @ArghaDebnath To plot phase just use `Arg`. Could you send me CV on https://www.docsie.io/ ?